# when I clone the code from git and run npm install on the machine, the error is like this. please help me

Tags: javascript

when I clone the code from git and run npm install on the machine, the error is like this. please help me

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\weather_app\complete-node-bootcamp\4-natours\after-section-14\node_modules\deasync
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./build.js
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.15.4 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\ADMIN\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ADMIN\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at callback (C:\Users\ADMIN\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:299:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:183:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\weather_app\complete-node-bootcamp\4-natours\after-section-14\node_modules\deasync
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.4
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-03T16_30_43_130Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I guess you need to install python and set in your env variable.

https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/

Comment: What code are you cloning. The error is saying that you need to install Python first. Do you have Python installed?

Comment: my code is javascript . i don't understand why python is here.